# Quiting a macOS App remotely via the command line

Tags: macos, vpn

I am trying to access my Mac mini on my home LAN from a remote location (I am currently on holiday in another country). I use AnyDesk but unfortunately I expanded a HUGE file to the boot drive by mistake... run out a disk space and AnyDesk is no longer responding!

I logged into the machine via a Wireguard VPN tunnel from my VPS and deleted the offending file so disk space is no longer an issue.

What is the easiest way to quit and relaunch AnyDesk remotely?

Rebooting the machine remotely is a last resort because Wireguard needs to be started manually at boot in macOS.

Any tips appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `sudo ps aux | grep -i “anydesk”`?

Comment: krusty           78748   0.0  0.0  4399408    760 s001  S+    9:57AM   0:00.00 grep -i “anydesk”

I have tried "sudo kill 760" but the process seems to be auto relaunching and I still cannot connect with the AnyDesk app

Comment: That means there’s a second helper process.  Can you post the output of `sudo ps aux`?

Answer (score 3):

You said you can remotely log into your Mac via the VPN, so you have two options:

- Launch AnyDesk via the command line:

  ```
   nohup /Applications/AnyDesk.app/Contents/MacOS/AnyDesk
  ```

  This should launch the App, allowing you to log in using the GUI and control your Mac as before
- Reboot by issuing the command `sudo reboot`.  This assumes if you have AnyDesk set to automatically launch when your computer starts.  If it only loads when you log in, then this option won’t work.

You can find AnyDesk command line options on their [Support site](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/command-line-interface-for-macos)

To kill an App, you can try the command

```
sudo pkill AnyDesk
```

That will terminate any process named AnyDesk

Comment: as with comment above the process is still active after running "sudo pkill AnyDesk" and cannot connect via the AnyDesk app